# how to insert multiple value into one column

Tags: php, mysql

here example `INSERT INTO table_name( user_id, user_balance) VALUES( 1, 500)`

but in my case I need  insert 1000 'user_id' from 1-1000 with same 'user_balace' for all user(500), how make function instead calling 1000 times one code

Comment: for example I need it do that

Comment: btw; you've many unclosed questions. The ones that were solved would help everyone to know they were solved.

Comment: Just set the default value for `user_balace` to 500, then every user that gets created will have that value.

Comment: aha understand , I will check , anyway thank you